# How to pass pending status of API request from Server Component to Client Component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a fetch function:

```
import { BuildingInfoRequestParams } from "../types"

export async function getBuildingInfo(requestParams: BuildingInfoRequestParams) {
  const { city, houseNumber, street, zipCode } = requestParams
  const url = `api`
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": `key`,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    cache: "force-cache",
  })

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data")
  }

  const data = await res.json()
  return {
    data: data[2],
  }
}
```

This function is used by the **Server Component** and this **Server Component** wraps a **Client Component** called `Form`

```
export const BuildingInfoForm = async () => {
  const requestParams = getRequestParams()
  const { data } = await getBuildingInfo(requestParams)
  return (
    <div className={styles["container"]}>
{**How to pass the status of fetch function here**}
        <Form data={data} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is my Client Component `Form`:

```
export const Form = ({ data }: { data: BuildingInfoAPIData }) => {
  const {
    fullStoreys: initialFullStoreys,
    constructionYearClass: initialConstructionYearClass,
    livingSpace: initialLivingSpace,
    buildingType: initialBuildingType,
  } = data
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false) // How to track the fetch function here from the Server Component

  /// other code

return isLoading ? (
    <h1>Loading</h1>
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
{**Form components**}
<Fragment>
```